# Wordcloud error in R/Rmarkdown: Cannot run two Wordclouds in a row without the second one cropping or excluding several words

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am trying to create multiple word clouds in a for loop in R Markdown using the Wordcloud package/function. The first wordcloud always looks great, but the following ones are always cropped weirdly, excluding multiple words and chopping off parts of words.

I am providing a simple R example (instead of RMarkdown) because the issue appears here as well. My end goal is to use this in RMarkdown knitting to Word.

I use an example dataset from the Wordcloud2 package but I would like to stick with the Wordcloud package, if possible. I split the demoFreq dataset in half for the purposes of this example.

```
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud2)

first = demoFreq[1:506,]
second = demoFreq[507:1011,]

wordcloud(words = first$word, freq = first$freq, min.freq = 3,           
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35,            
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

wordcloud(words = second$word, freq = second$freq, min.freq = 3,           
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35,            
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

The first Wordcloud looks like this:
[image]

And the second Wordcloud looks like this, with several warnings saying certain words were excluded from the wordcloud (e.g., "housing could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted."):

[image]

Adjusting the scale parameter does not fix the problem, it only seems to affect the first wordcloud again and the others are still messed up.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: it looks like `wordcloud` plots in base R, so I'm guessing the issue is that the plot `par` and `mar` type stuff is getting carried over when you don't want it to. Does adding `plot.new` between `wordcloud` calls fix your issue?

Comment: Adding both ```plot.new()``` and ```frame()``` between the plots worked! Thank you for the help!